# Exponential sums of fully singular hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a prime and let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be the field with $p$ elements.
Let $\chi: \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{C}$ be an additive character, and let $f \in \mathbb{F}_p [x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be a polynomial with $d = \deg (f)$.
Let us consider the exponential sum
$$ S (f, \chi) = \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{F}_p^n} \chi \big( f (\mathbf{x}) \big). $$

One usually has the multivariate version of Weil's bound
$$ | S (f, \chi) | \leq d \cdot p^{n - 1 / 2}. $$

To improve this bound [Deligne](https://eudml.org/doc/103930) studied the homogeneous highest degree part $f_d$ of $f$.
If the projective hypersurface $\mathcal{V}_+ (f_d) \subset \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^{n - 1}$ is non-singular, then Deligne's improved bound is
$$ | S (f, \chi) | \leq (d - 1)^n \cdot p^{n / 2}. $$

In the literature I found two approaches to bound the exponential sum when $\mathcal{V}_+ (f_d)$ admits singularities.
Denote with $\text{Sing} (f_d) \subset \mathcal{V}_+ (f_d)$ the singular locus (as closed subscheme) of the hypersurface.

1. [Katz](https://doi.org/10.1155/S1073792899000458) proved that if $\dim \big( \text{Sing} (f_d) \big) \leq \delta$ (plus some technical conditions), then
   $$ | S (f, \chi) | \leq C (d,n) \cdot p^{(n + \delta - 1 / 2}, $$
   where $C (d, n)$ is a (computable) constant depending on $d$ and $n$.
2. [Garcia](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002290050084) studied the case when the singularities of $\mathcal{V}_+ (f_d)$ are isolated (plus some technical conditions), then
   $$ | S (f, \chi) | \leq (d - 1)^n \cdot p^{n / 2}. $$

**Problem/Question:** I am interested in estimates of $| S (f, \chi) |$ when $\mathcal{V}_+ (f_d)$ is fully degenerated, i.e. $\mathcal{V}_+ (f_d) = \text{Sing} (f_d)$.
In this scenario, are there any estimates for the exponential sum that are of the order $\mathcal{O} (p^{n / 2})$?
Or, are there known (generic) counterexamples that exceed $\mathcal{O} (p^{n / 2})$?

**Remark:** If $\mathcal{V}_+ (f_d) = \text{Sing} (f_d)$, then $\dim \big( \text{Sing} (f_d) \big) = n - 2$ and therefore Katz's bound is in $\mathcal{O} (p^{n - 1/2})$.